# Nginx works only on port 80 when trying to reverse proxy nodejs server

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, nginx, pm2, ufw

I'm trying to start a virtual machine with Nginx and to run 2 nodejs apps in it.
I want them to be accessed like this:
APP 1: example.com:81
APP 2: example.com:82

but only when I configure the reverse proxy to be on port 80 it works..

NGINX CONFIGURATION:

```
upstream app_yourdomain {
    server 127.0.0.1:3000;
    keepalive 8;
}

# the nginx server instance
server {
    listen 81;
#    listen [::]:81;
    server_name mydomain.com www.mydomain.com;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/servicename.log;

    location / {
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
      proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

      proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/;
      proxy_redirect off;
    }
 }
```

netstat -napl relevant lines:

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:81              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
```

ufw

```
81                         ALLOW       Anywhere
OpenSSH (v6)               ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
80/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
80,443/tcp (v6)            ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
Nginx Full (v6)            ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
Nginx HTTP (v6)            ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
3000 (v6)                  ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
3001 (v6)                  ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
81 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

why isn't it working on port 81?
if i'll change my nginx conf for this app to port 80 it will work on the default domain..

my domain's dns managed by cloudflare and pointed as proxy to the ip of the vm

pm2 manages my node process'

any suggestions?